# Reading a key/value file in Java (alternative to Properties file)

Tags: java, xml, properties-file

I am trying to create a .rule (or a simple *.txt file) file which would be of key/value pair

```
rule1="A+B"
rule2="A-B"
rule3="A/B"
rule4="A*B"
```

I am already using the config.properties file to store all the key configuration.

```
DBpassword="US1232"
DBusername="abcde"
URI="http"
```

I don't want to mix both the config files with the rules. Do we some existing libraries for reading a key/value file. Or should I create an XML file structure for it.

Comment: why not use a property file? Java has the `Properties` class that does exactly what you need

Comment: Java's `Properties` class has [methods that can be used to load from a file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.Reader)).

Comment: I am already using `Properties`. I want to seperate those files, as I can use a seperate file with different extension to update the rules whenever needed. other reason is that user dont mess up the config file which updating the rules

Comment: "I don't want to mix both the config files with the rules." - that's all fine but what prevents you from using 2 .properties files? (note you can name one .rule, they don't have to have the .properties suffix).

Comment: @Thomas, that's right. If I don't find an alternative, I would use that in the end.

Comment: `Properties` is a file content concept, not a file extension. And as your rules are structurally identical to `Properties`, re-inventing the wheel would cause additional redundant code.

Comment: @Smutje, I agree. The rational was to have different file extensions to be able to provide the end user with easier identification. (If nothing works, I would end up having a file E.g. `rules.properties`)

Comment: @Betafish Have you read the link @DimaSan posted? When loading `Properties`, you *have* to specify the file extension - `Properties` does *not* assume your file extension *is* `.properties`.

Comment: As already stated in multiple ways using properties files (with different extensions) would be an easy way. I'd not change the file format just to prevent users from editing the wrong file (they'd do it anyways ;) ) so just stick with what works best, i.e. if the properties format is sufficient and you got it running already there's no need to switch.

Comment: @Smutje thanks, you are right, this is different question.

Comment: @DimaSan Sorry, I think you misunderstood me - I found your link helpful!

Comment: @DimaSan (Smutje), I have decided to go with the properties class. I have just renamed the extention to .rules (as you guys suggested).